# Editable JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I Have a JTable that i used SQL Query to fill. i also made the Cells Editable any cell i edit isnt getting saved and it just restores back to what it was once i finish editing.

im not completely sure what is the correct method to make the JTable completly editable and any cell that is being updated will save on the JTable itself and will get updated on the SQL Database.

i figured i should use TableModelListener with fireTableCellUpdated but i couldnt get it to work.

this is the code im using to show the JTable

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test_Table extends JPanel {
    //Load Componenets
    JTable table;
    static TableModel dataModel;
    static Connection conn;
    static Statement stmt;  
    static Vector<Vector<String>> resultVector=new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    static Vector<String> fieldVector=new Vector<String>();
    String[] col_name = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};


    //Get Data from SQL Database
    public static void getTableData(Vector<Vector<String>>resultVector, Vector<String>fieldVector) throws SQLException {
        fieldVector.clear();
        resultVector.clear();
        int colCount;
        String query="SELECT *FROM test_table WHERE DATE(time_stamp)=CURDATE() ORDER BY time_stamp DESC";
        ResultSet result;
        result=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData=result.getMetaData();
        colCount=metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i=0; i<colCount; i++)
            fieldVector.add(metaData.getCatalogName(i+1));
        for (int i=0; result.next(); i++) {
            resultVector.add(new Vector<String>());
        for (int j=0; j<colCount; j++)
            resultVector.get(i).add(result.getString(j+1));
        }
    }

    public Test_Table() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        //Connection to the SQL Database
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_table";
          final String username = "";
          final String password = "";
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        stmt=conn.createStatement();

        //Model to Create JTable filled with SQL Database
        getTableData(resultVector,fieldVector);
            dataModel=new AbstractTableModel(){
            public int getColumnCount() {return fieldVector.size();}
            public int getRowCount() {return resultVector.size();}
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return resultVector.get(row).get(col);
            }
               public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                   return true;
                }


               public String getColumnName(int index) {
                return col_name[index];
            }

        };

        //Adds TableMode Listener
        dataModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                try {
                    tableModelTableChanged(e);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        //Create JTable with Database and add to JPanel
        table=new JTable(dataModel);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1500,400));
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRenderer);
        final JScrollPane scrollpane=new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollpane);
    }

    public void tableModelTableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) throws SQLException{
          ?????????
        }

    //Update JTable when new row Inserted
    public static void update_table() throws SQLException {
    getTableData(resultVector, fieldVector);
    ((AbstractTableModel) dataModel).fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    //Close SQL Connection
    static void close() throws SQLException {
        if (stmt!=null)stmt.close();
        if(conn!=null) conn.close();
    }



    public void processWindowEvenet(WindowEvent e) {
        if (e.getID()==WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
            try {
                Testing_Table.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, SQLException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Testing_Table());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. you have to use SwingWorker, Runnable#Thread for JDBC#UPDATE..., 2. override JTable.setValueAt, 3. JDBC#Connection.OPEN / CLOSE are hard and long event at runtime, 4 . create some notifier (thats returns an exception to the screen) from JDBC if is there something failed (separate class. void that must contains oriinal coordinates inside JTable / XxxTableModel)

Answer (score 0):

The [TableModelEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) tells you which data has been changed. It's up to you to write the logic and craft the appropriate JDBC call to update the data in the DB.

Since the data in the JTable is already changed by the user. There's not point in updateing it again from the DB.

And yes, @mKorbel is right that you should do this in a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). But to start it might be easier to just implement everything in your `tableModelTableChanged()` method first and refactor it afterwards.

Comment: i am quite new with JAVA overall. and i never experienced with SwingWorker. maybe you can give me an example or some kind of a reference point?